# PhpStorm Localhost in root directory

Tags: phpstorm

When running a project in PhpStorm it takes me to localhost:63342/MyProject/index.php but this breaks all of the links because it adds the project name to the URL of my links work because on the domain it they are all mysite.com/image1.jpg, mysite.com/file2.htm, etc...

Is there a way to make it run the project as http://localhost:63342/index.php instead of http://localhost:63342/MyProject/index.php.

I've tried everything I can think of but I can't seem to figure this one out. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do `http://localhost:63342/index.php` -- only `http://MyProject:63342/index.php` (IDE still needs to know what site/files to serve somehow). For that:

1. **Edit your `hosts` file** (or local DNS server, if preferred and have one) and point `MyProject` to your computer's IP.
2. **Create Deployment entry** of correct type (`In Place` should do), configure it (provide desired URL etc -- `http://MyProject:63342/`) **and mark it as Default** for this project -- now IDE will use URL from there when generating "open in browser" URLs.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. http://MyProject:63342/MyProject/index.php works but not http://MyProject:63342/index.php. Any idea why?

Comment: @tumber033 What IP do you get when you do `ping MyProject`?

Comment: @tumber033 Then it should work (especially if it resolves to correct IP). BTW -- it's `localhost:63342/MyProject/index.php` vs `MyProject:63342/index.php` -- you seems to made a typo in your first comment. In any case -- it's definitely working as I have been giving this as a solution in quite few more questions like this + used it myself (for testing only though; back in v9).

Comment: @LazyOne I got it working by renaming the project (File -> Rename). Could the problem be due to a conflict in names? Does PhpStorm store a list of project names somewhere?

Comment: @tumber033 It definitely could be. By default project name would be the root folder name, so if you have some common name (like `httpdocs`) it may cause issues with identifying which one to serve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94826/discussion-between-tumber033-and-lazyone).