# Absolute path In WebStorm

Tags: html, webstorm

I've created a simple project to which I want to link 3 files: `angular.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.js` and `app.js` like in the picture below:

[image]

This looks ok, no warnings. If I press **Run** while in index.html the following errors appear:
[image]

In order for the errors to disappear I have to place the name of the project (**NewOne**) before each file I reference in `index.html`. Ex: `... src=/NewOne/angular/angular.min.js ...`

This generates warnings and disables the **⌘+click** shortcut to go the that file.

What is the correct way to specify absolute paths in WebStorm?

Comment: You are using WebStorm's simple built-in web server, right? If you want to keep using it instead of proper web server -- **1)** Try marking project root as Resource Root (wild guess; most likely will do nothing .. but works with subfolders) **2)** If #1 did not helped -- only by changing URLs from `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/file` to `PROJECT_NAME:63342/file` -- few steps job (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30084552/783119 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24908091/783119 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/29757139/783119)

Comment: @LazyOne: Is this what you meant: http://imgur.com/jz7sjr6 when you told me about 1)?

Comment: Thanks! Variant 2) works. Creating a deployment entry (of type `In Place`) and altering the `hosts` file is the correct solution. :D

Comment: Please note that deployment is only needed if you planning to use `Open in Browser` action (and maybe in some other moments, e.g. debugging (unsure though)). For just serving files it is not actually required.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that. I just hated that I couldn't go to that file with cmd+click since i had to write the project name before the reference to the file. But now it works without the project name :)

Answer (score 1):

With WebStorm version 2019.2 i did the following:

1 Edit in your windows hosts file the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 MyProject
```

2 Go in Webstorm to "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment" and add a new deployment location as type "in place". 
In the field "Web server URL:" you have to input "http://MyProject:63342/". Click Apply and it should work.

Now the following URLs should be working:

```
http://localhost:63342/MyProject/index.html -> uses relatie paths
http://MyProject:63342/index.html -> uses absolute paths
```

Please be aware that the port 63342 is the standard port of Webstorm. Maybe you have to change it to your specific port.