# PHPStorm does not find files for built-in server (HTTP 404)

Tags: phpstorm

I ran into issues with PHPStorm not delivering the website, but returns HTTP 404. I need to setup PHPStorm in a way that it does not serve files from a subdirectory. I know, numerous questions like this have been asked before, so I'll make quite clear what I have configured and tried.

I'm on Windows 10 1903 and I'm using PHPStorm 2019.3 (latest version at the time asking this question)

1. I have added an entry in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` to get a name mapped to localhost

   ```
   # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
   #   127.0.0.1       localhost
   #   ::1             localhost

   127.0.0.1   eigener-prozessor
   ```
2. I can ping it

   ```
   C:\Users\T>ping eigener-prozessor

   Pinging eigener-prozessor [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
   Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
   Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
   Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

   Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
       Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
   ```
3. In PHPStorm, the debugger is set to port 63342. And I allow unsigned requests (not sure if that really has an effect). I can't check "external connections".

   [image: Debugger port]
4. In PHPStorm, I have set up an in-place deployment as default, using the host and debugger port

   [image: Inplace deployment]
5. I made sure the mapping is on the root path

   [image: Mapping]
6. I have renamed my project to match the host name (File / Rename Project ...)

   [image: Project name]
7. I have configured a PHP CLI interpreter and made a `php.ini` available

   [image: PHP interpreter]
8. I have marked the source and resource directory

   [image: Directory configuration]
9. I do make sure that I do not open a local file in a browser but use the buttons for that

   [image: Use buttons]
10. It brings me to the correct URL but with HTTP 404. You can see that it serves from PHPStorm 2019.3.1, which is basically correct

    [image: Resulting HTTP 404 page]
11. In the web developer tools, I see that the IP address is 127.0.0.1

    [image: Web developer tools]

I have used the following SO questions as input:

- [How do I get PHPStorm to use the correct path for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053204/how-do-i-get-phpstorm-to-use-the-correct-path-for-css)
- [Absolute path In WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951620/absolute-path-in-webstorm) (PHPStorm might be similar)
- [PhpStorm Localhost in root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756999/phpstorm-localhost-in-root-directory)

I have also tried:

- using Chrome instead of Firefox

If I add `eigener-prozessor` as a subdirectory, the website can be accessed - but the resources cannot be loaded, because they point to `/css/something.css`, which is exactly why I went through all these steps.

[image: URL with subdirectory]

I'm out of ideas. How do I configure the built-in webserver to serve its stuff on the root (`/`)?

Please do not suggest a workaround like "use Apache" or "change the path to your resources". I have paid for the software and I expect the built-in webserver to work.

Comment: 1) You are on Windows -- why not use full IIS? It works just fine (yes, will need to configure it a bit, but it works just fine -- using it myself for many years). 2) PhpStorm's simple built-in web server may throw 502 errors from time to time for a perfectly valid pages. I suggest using PHP's built-in web server -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php . To run it -- just see answer from **Jeto** -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration-php-built-in-web-server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood something, a simple way to achieve what you need would be to [create a custom Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) of type `PHP Built-in Web Server`:

- Type Ctrl+Shift+A (or double shift) and look for `Edit Configurations...`
- Hit the `+` button on the top left to add a new one
- Select `PHP Built-in Web Server`
- Set `Host` to "eigener-prozessor", `Port` to 63342.
- The `Document Root` field should default to the root of the project, otherwise set it to that
- Rename configuration, adjust other values if needed, then click OK

You should then simply be able to run said configuration with the green triangle/associated hotkey and access the project files directly under http://eigener-prozessor:63342/.

Comment: Hmm ... I can run a server that way, but then I have to type the URL into the browser manually.

Comment: You can have the run configuration launch your browser whenever you run it (look for "Before launch"), but yeah, it will not open it to the file you were editing (due to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-689), mostly). What you could do instead is use the External Tools capability of the IDE. You could have a small bash script that would run the PHP built-in server with the right parameters, then open your browser of choice to the right URL using a macro. Then you'd bind a hotkey to it and run it whenever.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with `hosts` file doesn't work anymore, please follow [WEB-38141](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38141) for updates. So there is currently no way to set up the built-in web server to serve files from root